# Set Object Position

Tags: game-engine

I have a question that may or may not be confusing, so bear with me. In my characters right hand, their are two states. One state is for walking around without a weapon equipped, and the other state has his hand just pointing outwards as if a gun were in his hand. I don't need an animation in the weapon state, but I want the hand to stay stuck pointing outwards. How do I achieve this? -No python pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood this, but...
If your weapon does not stay stuck out when you press key to do it, than your logic syntax should be like this:

`Always(pulsed) -> And(state1) -> Weapon not stucked out(IDK what do you use for it)
Keyboard(the key to switch) -> And(state1) -> State(set state: 2)`

`Always(pulsed) -> And(state2) -> Weapon stucked out
Keyboard(the key to switch) -> And(state2) -> State(set state: 1)`

This should work, but I am not sure so that is what you want. Anyway, in my game this syntax did not for for some reason. I use 2.72b. When I did it all, it just did not change state when I pressed the key to do it in-game.

Good luck with it, anyway!;)

Edit:
If you ask how to make weapon position in each of the states, use this:

For weapon equiped:

Make tabs as in default view(3Dview in center, timeline on bottom)
Select first frame.
Position weapon as you need it to be positioned.
Press I and select LocRotScale.
Go to logic tab and in Weapon not stucked out(which I shown on top) select action.
Make it play, TheWeaponMeshNameAction in list of aviable actions and frist frame:1, end frame: 1.

Do the same for weapon unequipped, but put it in frame 2 and select frame 2 in action.

In second state I would reccomend you to make weapon placed in character's belt or something...

Comment: I asked basically if there was a logic brick or something to hold position.

Comment: Maybe use always with pulse and states. Always should hold position and states should switch between 2 always actuators. But use pulse in always...

Comment: I know that, but what are the bricks I would use? Always > And > ?

Comment: I think it might be Action. Use action and frame, in which you set weapon position to the one you want in each situation;)